# Assigning cell array to structure MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct, cell-array

Here is my JSON File

```
"Matlab_NX":

{"n1":

"Geometrieparameter":

{"Hoehe":1,

"Anzahl":1},

"Geometriepunkte":["-6.48201,8.02327,1.2","-9.64211,11.87299"]}.
```

I need to update values of a in JSON file.

a is an array

```
a=[X,Y,Z];


a =

   -6.4820       8.0233       1.2000

   -9.6421      11.8730       1.2000
```

I have used this command:

```
J.Matlab_NX.n1.Geometriepunkte=a;
```

Result:

```
"Geometriepunkte":[[-6.48201,8.02327,1.2],[-9.64211,11.87299,1.2]
```

but my desired output is:

```
"Geometriepunkte":["-6.48201,8.02327,1.2","-9.64211,11.87299,1.2"]
```

Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Why is your desired output missing a value? Do you want it to be a string?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typing mistake. I want it to write in a string as given in desired output

Comment: @AnderBiguri Could you help me? How to write Array a in string ?

Comment: You mean the easily googleable `num2str`? or did that not work?

Comment: it helped. but there are alot of empty spaces in my result. : "Geometriepunkte":["-6.48201      8.02327          1.2","-9.64211       11.873          1.2"

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to string with the proper format specification, and then tidy it a bit:

```
a2=num2str(a,'%g,'); 
a2(:,end)=[]; %remove the last coma.
```

Anything else you may need to modify, you can probably do by changing the `formatspec` to the right thing you want.

Note that if you want different length strings you need to deal with this differently.